# Counting chars in ruby 1.9.3 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I'm counting string length as shown below:

```
if(key['name'].to_s.chars.length==0)
  key['name']="Others"
end
```

And on ruby 2.1.8p440 it works, but on ruby 1.9.3p551 it throws following error:

```
(undefined method `length' for #<Enumerator: "Latency":chars>):
```

I cannot update 1.9.3 I must change this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What’s wrong with more explicit:

```
key['name'] = "Others" if key['name'].to_s.empty?
```

that works everywhere?

---

BTW, in ruby 1.9.3 there is no `Enumerable#length` there is [`Enumerable#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-count). The alias `length` it received later.

Comment: The `.to_s` is likely there to handle nils. In which case, it can be even shorter, `if key['name'].blank?`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I bet for symbols.

Comment: @AleksandarPavić: what errors? Also, what's the value of `key['name']` in those cases?

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby 1.9.3 [String#`chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chars)

> Passes each character in str to the given block, or **returns an enumerator if no block is given.**

So converting it to an array before calling `length` should solve the issue:

```
key['name'].to_s.chars.to_a.count == 0 # or size ?
```

Answer (score 0):

try `key['name'].to_s.mb_chars.length` . hope this will help u .

Answer (score 0):

You question is tagged with `ruby-on-rails` which has the [`blank?`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) and [`presence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence) methods. With that methods I would write something like:

```
if key['name'].blank?
  key['name'] = 'Others'
end
```

Or:

```
key['name'] = 'Others' if key['name'].blank?
```

Or:

```
key['name'] = key['name'].presence || 'Others'
```

Comment: The last one feels weird IMHO.

Comment: @EricDuminil The last one is almost the same as the examples in the Rails docs. IMHO a perfect example why the `presence` method was introduced.

Comment: I don't like overriding a value with itself when it's not necessary. The second example (the best one IMHO) doesn't touch `key['name']` when already defined.

Comment: I see. I kind of agree with you given this small example. It really depends on the OP uses the value later on. I would prefer the second version too.